NetSuite saved search: field showing internal number instead of name
I created a saved search in NetSuite. One of the fields named "Parent Sub" shows an internal ID instead of a name. but when I see the page by clicking view from result, I see the "parent sub" field showing the name. What should I do? 
I want to see name not internal id for this field

usually, when you use an id of a field, e.g. custbody59 and it has internalid of another record, which is a numeric value, e.g. '55' and you want to have text there, you should use custbody59:text (wrap it all in quotes if necessary) i.e. add the :text suffix to where you use the id of the field. You didn't provide any script or something like that to give a more precise advice
